# An error occurred while installing pg (1.4.1), and Bundler cannot continue - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run `bundle install` I get this error:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (1.4.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
```

I then run `gem install pg` and get this:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.4.5/.appveyor.yml
```

I thought it was a permission is so I ran : `sudo gem install pg` then I got this:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [pg_ext.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.4.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-22/2.7.0/pg-1.4.5/gem_make.out
```

gcc is installed and up to date.
Postgres 14.7
I followed most of the solutions on here and got nowhere. Does anyone know how to fix this?
I am on a M1 with MacOS Ventura